# How is the physical address calculated in Page tables?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, paging

Taking an example, say we have Page size = 4KB, Page Table Entry = 4B, Physical Address Space requires 36 bits

In 3-level multi-paging, let's say the number of entries in the level 3 page table is 2^9 (so the size of this page table would be 2^9 * 4B = 2^11 B )
In level 2, there are 2^9 entries as well and finally in level 1 (the outermost) we have 2^2 entries.
Now the question is:

Let's say we have a physical address = [some 25 bit number | 00..000 (11 zeroes)] = X
and say this denotes the 1st entry in PT2.
Should the PA(physical address) for the next entry in PT2 be [that same 25 bit number| 00...001 (11 bits)] = X + 1

or should it be [that same 25 bit number| 00...100 (11 bits)] = X + 4.

I think it should be the latter.

Since we only have 2^9 entries in PT2 but the offset bits for each page PT2 is 11 bits, so we have to group some bits of every 11 bits to get each of the 2^9 entries.

I have tried referencing texts but I'm not able to find a concrete answer for the physical address translation. Any light shedded would be very much appreciated.